# Java, Make sure a String contains only alphanumeric, spaces and dashes

Tags: java, string, parsing, contains

In Java, I need to make sure a String only contains `alphanumeric`, `space` and `dash` characters.

I found the class `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils` and the almost adequate method `isAlphanumericSpace(String)`... but I also need to include dashes.

What is the best way to do this?  I don't want to use Regular Expressions.

Comment: I also saw in the same library the method containsOnly(String, char[]), but that means I'd have to list the entire alphabet, numbers from 0 to 9 and a space and a dash... seems a little over explicit for what I need to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hum... just program it yourself using *String.chatAt*(**int**), it's pretty easy...

Iterate through all **char** in the string using a position index, then compare it using the fact that ASCII characters 0 to 9, a to z and A to Z use consecutive codes, so you only need to check that character x numerically verifies one of the conditions:

- between '0' and '9'
- between 'a' and 'z'
- between 'A and 'Z'
- a space ' '
- a hyphen '-'

Here is a basic code sample (using CharSequence, which lets you pass a String but also a StringBuilder as arg):

```
public boolean isValidChar(CharSequence seq) {
    int len = seq.length();
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {
        char c = seq.charAt(i);
        // Test for all positive cases
        if('0'<=c && c<='9') continue;
        if('a'<=c && c<='z') continue;
        if('A'<=c && c<='Z') continue;
        if(c==' ') continue;
        if(c=='-') continue;
        // ... insert more positive character tests here
        // If we get here, we had an invalid char, fail right away
        return false;
    }
    // All seen chars were valid, succeed
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I would use the java.lang.Character tests instead of making assumptions based on the ASCII character set.

Comment: Yes, Character.isLetterOrDigit() does that, but it comes with a very notable performance cost (4 or 5 times slower than a simple code point comparison).

Comment: It will reject lots of other valid alpha characters - that just aren't used much in English, just so it will take 1 μs instead of 4μs.  (yeah it'll reject "μs"  :-) )

Making assumptions he didn't say in order to get a minor performance gain he didn't ask for isn't a good idea.

Comment: Consider SkipHead's suggestion to use StringUtils.isAlphanumericSpace, in my humble opinion it is much nicer.

Answer (score 13):

You could use:

```
StringUtils.isAlphanumericSpace(string.replace('-', ' '));
```

Comment: For clarity SkipHead means StringUtils.isAlphanumericSpace(String), and this is much nicer than hand coding an interative check.

Answer (score 3):

Just iterate through the string, using the character-class methods in java.lang.Character to test whether each character is acceptable or not. Which is presumably all that the StringUtils methods do, and regular expressions are just a way of driving a generalised engine to do much the same.

Answer (score 1):

You have 1 of 2 options:
1.  Compose a list of chars that CAN be in the string, then loop over the string checking to make sure each character IS in the list.
2.  Compose a list of chars that CANNOT be in the string, then loop over the string checking to make sure each character IS NOT in the list.

Choose whatever option is quicker to compose the list.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use a regex expression. There's no point in writing your own system when a very comprehensive system in place for this exact task. If you need to learn about or brush up on regex then check out this website, it's great: http://regexr.com

I would challenge yourself on this one.